# Query time range

Tags: sql, postgresql, time, range

What I need is to select available exams for registration that are not yet registered by the student (done) and, the one that I am having trouble, is also to see if the time (start/end) of these available exams do not conflict to some exam that the student had registered before.

I am using PostgreSQL and Clojure. 
The database is like this:

```
 -- exam ----------------------------------
| exam_id (PK integer)                     |
| exam_date (date)                         |
| exam_start_time (time without time zone) |
| exam_end_time (time without time zone)   |
| ...                                      |
 ------------------------------------------

 -- student -----------------
| student_redid (PK integer) |
| ...                        |
 ----------------------------

 -- student_exam --------------
| student_exam_id (PK integer) |
| student_redid (student FK)   |
| exam_id (exam FK)            |
| ...                          |
 ------------------------------
```

The query I am using to select the available exams (using :redid as parameter):

```
SELECT *
FROM exam ex
WHERE exam_id NOT IN (SELECT exam_id
    FROM student_exam
    WHERE student_redid = :redid)
ORDER BY ex.exam_id ASC,
         ex.exam_date DESC
```

I need to improve this query by verifying if the available exams do not conflict with the exams in a query similar to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM student_exam
WHERE student_redid = :redid
```

Well, I now about the use of BETWEEN, but do not understand how to verify time ranges using nested queries.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First you select all exams this student haven't register yet
- Then check if that exam collide with any other exam this is student is already register

.

```
SELECT *
FROM exam newEx
WHERE 
    NOT EXIST (SELECT se.exam_id
               FROM student_exam se
               WHERE 
                   se.student_redid = :redid
               AND se.exam_id = newEx.exam_id)
AND NOT EXIST (SELECT se.exam_id 
               FROM 
                   student_exam se inner join
                   exam oldEx on se.exam_id = oldEx.exam_id 
               WHERE 
                   student_redid = :redid
               AND newEx.exam_start_time <= oldEx.exam_end_time
               AND newEx.exam_end_time   >= oldEx.exam_start_time
               AND newEx.exam_date = oldEx.exam_date
              )
ORDER BY 
    newEx.exam_id ASC,
    newEx.exam_date DESC
```

Comment: I just had to change the ORDER BY to newEx instead of ex and add the date condition:
AND newEx.exam_date = oldEx.exam_date

Thats working, thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry about that, I create alias New and Old to make it more readable and miss that part. I usually create a fiddle first, but for this one didnt have time. I suggest for your next sql question provide the schema and data in something like this [sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/42897/5).